# Is there a common unique ID type across all computers and phones retrievable by using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking to allow one-time access to a feature I'm building but didn't want to hassle users with creating a username and password to use. However, I would need to keep tabs so I was wondering if Node.js has the ability to retrieve some kind of unique ID that spans across all computers, tablets and phones? Does such an ID exist?

My initial thought was to use the MAC address but the only fault is that it is dependent on the network the device is on. So if my users are using their smartphones, then it may change.

Thanks!

Comment: try to make your own? https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto

Comment: You can set one yourself, https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: How would I be able to check against it the next time the device is using the app? I am trying to avoid saving anything generated in browser/device storage because it could be erased or not saved at all if someone is using an incognito window.

Comment: For obvious security reasons, such data does not exist and uuid+local storage is your best bet

Comment: MAC address can be changed by the user and or not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks guys!